# std::min_element getting the result for the iterator

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<double> cMinDist;
    for (int i = 0; i < mc_4.size(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<double> temp;
        for (int j = 0; j <  mc_4.size(); j++)
        {
            if (j == i)
            {
                continue;
            }    
            temp.push_back( sqrt(pow(mc_4[i].x - mc_4[j].x,2) + pow(mc_4[i].y - mc_4[j].y,2)));         
        }

        std::vector<double>::iterator result =std::min_element(std::begin(temp),std::end(temp));
        cMinDist[i] =result; //error is here

    }
```

well get this error

```
11  IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>" to "double" exists
```

how can I extract the result from the iterator, not the index number just the result?

Do I  really need to do something like:

```
int index = std::distance(std::begin(temp), result);
cMinDist[i] =temp[index];
```

or is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dereference the iterator.

```
cMinDist[i] = *result;
```

Iterators are a generalization of pointers. As such, they are modeled after them.

Comment: Thanks I always forget that, I will accept the answer in 10 mins. it's working.

Answer (score 1):

For iterators of class std::vector (they belong to the category of random access iterators) you can use records either

```
cMinDist[i] = *result;
```

or

```
cMinDist[i] = result[0];
```

by analogy with pointers.:)

The only difference with pointers in records is that for pointers you may write

```
0[p];
```

but for iterators you may not write the same:)

```
0[it];
```